# How to round up the result without losing its precision in android

Tags: java, rounding, precision, bigdecimal

I am building a basic calculator functionality in android.
But I am facing little problem with rounding up the numbers when the result is get displayed in the TextView.

I am doing multiplication of 123456789 * 123456789 and getting result which I am not able to accommodate in my TextView.
Also the Actual result of above operation is 1.5241E16 when performed in Android's in built Calculator.
Can anyone tell me that how can I achieve this result in my calculator app?
Below is little snippet about what I am trying to do:

```
public static double round(double unrounded, int precision, int roundingMode)
    {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
        BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(precision, roundingMode);
        return rounded.doubleValue();
    }

    num = num * Double.parseDouble(txtCalc.getText().toString());
    num = round(num, 3, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); //where 3 is the precision of number
```

Plz Help me to achieve the result 1.5241E16 for 1...9 * 1....9

Comment: I'm confused, what result are you getting? The scientific notation **does** lose accuracy. 1.5241E16 simply means the answer is roughly 1.5241*10,000,000,000,000,000 meaning if you can decide how many decimal places you want to display, you can just divide you number by 10^X and concatenate the result.

Comment: Ya, the same way I also just want to round up my result to 1.5241E16.

Comment: I've added code to my answer below that gives the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scientific notation **does** lose accuracy. 1.5241E16 simply means the answer is roughly 1.5241*10,000,000,000,000,000 meaning if you can decide how many decimal places you want to display, you can just divide you number by 10^X and concatenate the result.

So if my resulting number was 1234567890 and I wanted to display this to 3 decimal places. I would do 1234567890 / 10^9 (because there are 9 digits after the first digit) and then I would simply cancatenate everything after char 5 (1 place for the whole number, 1 place for the dot and then 3 decimal places). If you want to round the last decimal place, simply check if the number at position 6 is greater than or eqaul to 5 and just increment the last number by 1.

Here this gives the result you desire.

```
double num1 = 123456789L;
double num2 = 123456789L;
String result = num1*num2+"";
if(result.contains("E")){ //if result is in scientific notation
    //take the first 6 characters only and part containing the E, drop everything else.
    result = result.substring(0, 6) + result.substring(result.indexOf("E"));
}
System.out.println("Result is = " + result);
```

The output from my Groovy shell:

> Result is = 1.5241E16

Comment: :But how to know the number of digits entered by the user? i.e. in your case it is 10^9. Any code snippet would be helpful to me as I am not so easy with Maths :). Thanks Ali

Comment: In the code above I just check for E before I do any concatenation. You would ofcourse have to put a few more checks in there for example if `result.indexOf("E") > 6` only then concatenate. Else your result is up to 4 decimal places anyways.

Comment: @ Ali : Thanks, It worked! Exactly what I was looking for. Will it work for all type of numbers in the range?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to rounding issue

```
package com.test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;

/**
 * @VinTech Blogs
 * @vintech2277.blogspot.com
 *
 */
public class SumSame 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
     String[] from= {"3.2571365449","4.87608977397","5.29831575733","1.5684579238"};
     BigDecimal[] fromBD = new BigDecimal[from.length];
     BigDecimal[] toBD = new BigDecimal[from.length];

     BigDecimal diff = new BigDecimal("0");
     int high = 0;
     int low = 0;

     for(int i=0;i0) if(fromBD[i].compareTo(fromBD[high]) > 0){
         high= i;
        }else if(fromBD[i].compareTo(fromBD[low]) < 0){
         low= i;
        }
      //set scale to 2 means 2 digits after decimal               
                // HALf_DOWN means 11.45 rounds to 11.4
                //HALF_UP means 11.45 rounds to 11.5
      toBD[i] = fromBD[i].setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
      diff = diff.add(fromBD[i].subtract(toBD[i]));
     }    

     //We get the difference here and allocate the diffs to highest or lowest based
     //on diff value type
     if(diff.doubleValue() > 0.0){
      toBD[low]=toBD[low].add(diff).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
     }else if(diff.doubleValue() < 0.0){
      toBD[high]=toBD[high].add(diff).setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
     }   

     for (BigDecimal bigDecimal : toBD) {
   System.out.println("val is "+bigDecimal);
  }
    }
}
```